# Multiple textboxes with same ngModel

Tags: angular

My object will decide number of textboxes on runtime. and those all textboxes have same ngModel Name. [(ngModel)]="childComment".  functionality wise it works. but when I write something in one textbox, it shows over all textboxes?  Thanks

```
<mat-form-field class="removetopmargin">
<input matInput  [(ngModel)]="childComment" placeholder="Reply here ..">
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: in the image I have written try your best, and shown in multiple textboxes.]

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: in image, I have written try your best, and shown in multiple textboxes.

Comment: you need to change the `ngModel` for each textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually do want the same value bound to the same property then update the value on blur instead of using ngModel.

```
<input matInput  [value]="childComment" (blur)="childComment = $event.target.value" placeholder="Reply here ..">
```

This mean that as you type the value is not updated until you move to another field and the blur event handler is fired.

See a demo here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stfyru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 [(ngModel)]="childComment"
```

Two way binds to a property of your component called childComment. If multiple controls are two way binding to the same property then they will all display the same value. You need a different property to bind to for each control.

You could have an array and loop through

```
controls = [
  { name: 'time', value: null },
  { name: 'fast', value: null }
];
```

and in your template

```
<mat-form-field class="removetopmargin" *ngFor="let control of controls">
  <input [name]="control.name" [(ngModel)]="control.value" placeholder="Reply here ..">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I can't have different ngModel properties. my scenario requires something like this. which is comment and their replies. and functionality wises its working. just during typing text is shown in multiple textboxes.     while I bind name attribute with different values but didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to define different names for every input such as:

```html
<input matInput [name]="dynamicNameHere" [(ngModel)]="childComment" placeholder="Reply here ..">
```

Comment: @NaveedUllah the issue is the data binding, make the `ngModel` dynamic instead

Comment: This is not how it should be written but `[name]="i.userName"` or `name="{{i.userName}}"` and be sure that every input has a different binded model through `ngModel`

Comment: I canot have multiple ngmodel on run time. as my object will decide number of textboxes on run time. @mast3rd3mon

Comment: @NaveedUllah please provide a working example or more code lines because it's not enough to help you

Comment: functionality wise it works.  the only issue i am having is that text shown on mulptiple textboxes. i think i should hide all the other textboxes the moment i write something in a specific textbox.

Answer (score -1):

You bind one model to some inputs. Because of that, every time that you want to write something, because they bind to the same variable, the result is same.